# OLEDB Command not generating a valid query

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbcommand

In my ASP.NET MVC application I have a form there the user can enter multiple texts.
I want to save those inputs as OleDbCommand Parameters to generate a SQL Script. Unfortunately it's not working and I don't know why as I don't know what exact script is generated.

I worked with OleDbCommand before and it worked fine for a simple script (just an Update with a where clause). But now I want to Insert a new row in my DB.

```C#
//Create OleDbCommand and add parameters
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Name); //This is a string
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myUser.myLoginUser._MySpAppS.Encrypt_AES(myNewMassnahme.Projektleiter.A_ID)); //this is a string
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.MassnahmenartID); //this is an int
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Umsetzungsweg); //this is a string
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Status_ID); //this is an int
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Massnahmenstart); //this is a DateTime
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Painpoint); //This is a string
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Loesung); //This is a string
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Beteiligte_User); //This is a string

//This is just to check what command is generated (but it only shows the query with the '?'
myCommand.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO MASSNAHMEN (NAME, PROJEKTLEITER_AID, MASSNAHMENART_ID, UMSETZUNGSWEG, STATUS_ID, MASSNAHMENSTART, PAINPOINT, LOESUNG, BETEILIGTE_USER) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, TO_DATE(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), ?, ?, ?);", myCommand.Parameters);


DataSet myDS = new DataSet();

//Make query on DB
//myUser.myLoginUser._MySpAppS.RunSQL simply runs a query on my DB. It expects a string and optional OleDbCommand.Parameters. It return a DataSet
myDS = myUser.myLoginUser._MySpAppS.RunSQL("INSERT INTO MASSNAHMEN (NAME, PROJEKTLEITER_AID, MASSNAHMENART_ID, UMSETZUNGSWEG, STATUS_ID, MASSNAHMENSTART, PAINPOINT, LOESUNG, BETEILIGTE_USER) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, TO_DATE(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), ?, ?, ?);", myCommand.Parameters);
```

I'm not getting any error message but I can see that no record is entered in my DB. I'm expecting a query like this:

```SQL
INSERT INTO MASSNAHMEN
  (NAME, PROJEKTLEITER_AID, MASSNAHMENART_ID, UMSETZUNGSWEG, STATUS_ID, MASSNAHMENSTART, PAINPOINT, LOESUNG, BETEILIGTE_USER)
  VALUES( 'Test', 'Test_AID', 1, 'TEST_UMSETZUNGSWEG', 1, TO_DATE('15.08.2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'Nothing works', 'Hopefully its getting better', 'Help!');
```

This is an example that worked totally fine:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", role.Description);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", role.ID);

DataSet myDS = new DataSet();
myDS = myUser.myLoginUser._MySpAppS.RunSQL("UPDATE Rollen SET DESCRIPTION=? WHERE ID=?;", myCommand.Parameters);
```

After that myDS contains one table and I can see the changes in my DB

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve]. The key here is that it must be code such that we can copy and paste it **as is, without modification** and run it in a console app.

Comment: @mjwills the value of it is: "INSERT INTO MARS$T_MASSNAHMEN (NAME, PROJEKTLEITER_AID, MASSNAHMENART_ID, UMSETZUNGSWEG, STATUS_ID, MASSNAHMENSTART, PAINPOINT, LOESUNG, BETEILIGTE_USER) VALUES ('?', '?', ?, '?', ?, TO_DATE('?', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), '?', '?', '?');" So the same as before. I used String.Format because I was trying to read the command but as I'm getting this result it's not useful for me. Do you have another suggestion how I can read the query after the values are filled in?

Comment: Something wrong in your thinking here: you make a command with no command text set (it doesn't generate one for you; that's what an oledbcommandbuilder is for), then you set a bunch of parameters, then you set a commandtext (write) but claim it's to check (read) the generated command (there is no generated command) - I think setting a new command may wipe the parameters (but I could be mistaken), then you create a dataset which is for storing data retrieved from a db via a SELECT but this is an INSERT, then you try and run the insert via a device intended to select and claim nothing inserted..

Comment: @CaiusJard I used it that way in an UPDATE statement before and it worked totally fine for me. First I created an empty command and added some parameters (only two) and then I started the query using our library. If it's helpful I can share the code too.

Comment: @CaiusJard - for future reference, setting the command text doesn't reset the parameters. The order of adding parameters, setting command type, text, timeout, all that stuff, doesn't matter, as long as it happens before executing.

Comment: Oh, the order of adding (individual) parameters definitely matter for oledb as they aren't named but I get your point, thanks for the update . Maybe I'm thinking of the VB6 days where setting a command text with placeholders "helpfully" populated the parameters collection with empty parameters

Comment: I didn't mean parameter order. I just meant parameters vs. other properties.

Comment: 99% of the time that a developer claims "my insert..values query didn't error and didn't insert any values" they were looking in the wrong db. The other 1% of the time they'd run it inside a try with a `catch{}` that swallowed the exception

Comment: The fact that you have to create a command object to create the parameters seems a bit ridiculous. You're not using the command object. Clearly, `RunSQL` is creating its own command object and copying the parameters over to that one's parameter collection. `RunSQL` should take `IEnumerable<OleDbParameter>` so you can construct an array or list and pass that instead of creating something else you have to dispose.

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm pretty sure I'm looking in the right table. Also I don't have a try catch block. Maybe the DateTime makes some problems? I will try that.

Comment: I can't help but wonder, though: what data source is on the other end of that connection? It's rare these days that you have to use OLEDB, especially if it's one of the big names, like SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ... Can you use a more specific ADO.NET provider?

Comment: I guess you just answered that last question.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing it, I'd do this:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand( SET A OLEDBCONNECTION HERE );
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MASSNAHMEN (NAME, PROJEKTLEITER_AID, MASSNAHMENART_ID, UMSETZUNGSWEG, STATUS_ID, MASSNAHMENSTART, PAINPOINT, LOESUNG, BETEILIGTE_USER) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Name); //This is a string
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myUser.myLoginUser._MySpAppS.Encrypt_AES(myNewMassnahme.Projektleiter.A_ID)); //this is a string
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.MassnahmenartID); //this is an int
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Umsetzungsweg); //this is a string
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Status_ID); //this is an int
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Massnahmenstart); //this is a DateTime
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Painpoint); //This is a string
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Loesung); //This is a string
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Beteiligte_User); //This is a string

int numRecordsInserted = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Things you need to fix, that I can't know:

- the name of your oledbconnection, should be passed to the command constructor
- the name of your db table: you change your mind as to what it is as you go through the code

Actually, saying "i'd do this" is a bit of a lie.  I'd either use strongly typed datasets or an ORM like dapper, entity framework or nhibernate.. but once upon a time before I knew of the wonders of these data access helpers, I'd have gone this laborious route :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I'm creating the OleDbCommand only to fill the Parameters and transmit them to our library which does the rest. I've amended my post with a running example.

Comment: You should always avoid telling someone who is trying to help you on SO a simple "it doesn't work" - it contains no detail to help solve the problem. Always say why it doesn't work, including exact error mrssages

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Problem: The DateTime was making problems.
I've changed:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Massnahmenstart);
```

To:

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("", myNewMassnahme.Massnahmenstart.ToShortDateString());
```

Now it works as expected

P.S.: And I also deleted the hours part in

```
TO_DATE(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: So were you swallowing the exception? By he way, you don't need to format your date into a string, pass the string to the db, and then get the db to parse it back to a date. The whole idea of using parameters is that you can add your date as a date, it gets sent to the db as a date and inserted as a date. If someone runs your app in America it may well start inserting the wrong dates because toshortdatestring is culture sensitive! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=netframework-4.8 using typed parameters properly avoids all this